# Merge Dataframe alonside and rename column

Tags: python, pandas

c:/somepath contains below files

> file1 file2 file3

from "c:/somepath/", I am capturing all the file names in a list called users

```
users=[d for d in os.listdir("c:/somepath/") if os.path.isdir(os.path.join("c:/somepath/", d))]
```

*Note: the number of files in the directory can differ, but the data in the file remains in the same format.*

file1 contains below data

```
index   user name   %used
 1          a        25
 2          a        40
 3          a        20
 4          a        25
```

file2 contains below data

```
index   user name   %used
 1          b        33
 2          b        66
 3          b        20
 4          b        88
```

file3 contains below data

```
index   user name   %used
 1          c        25
 2          c        69
 3          c        20
 4          c        73
```

**I need the result as shown below**

```
index     a     b    c
  1       25    33   25
  2       40    66   69
  3       20    20   20
  4       25    88   73
```

if you see the result, the %used column was renamed to respective "user name"

Could someone please tell me the easiest way to achieve this result.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC:

```
pd.concat(pd.read_fwf(f, index_col=[0, 1]).squeeze() for f in users).unstack()
```

### MCVE

I dropped those files into my directory

```
print(*(p.read_text() for p in Path('.').glob('file*')), sep='\n\n')

index   user name   %used
 1          a        25
 2          a        40
 3          a        20
 4          a        25

index   user name   %used
 1          b        33
 2          b        66
 3          b        20
 4          b        88

index   user name   %used
 1          c        25
 2          c        69
 3          c        20
 4          c        73
```

Then I ran the above code

```
from pathlib import Path

pd.concat(
    pd.read_fwf(f, index_col=[0, 1]).squeeze() for f in Path('.').glob('file*')
).unstack()

user name   a   b   c
index                
1          25  33  25
2          40  66  69
3          20  20  20
4          25  88  73
```

---

### Explanation

I'm using pandas `read_fwf` to read a fixed width file.  I set the first two columns as indices and squeeze the result.  This produces a `Series`.  Then I use `pd.concat` to put them all on top of one another.  After that I use `unstack` to unwind the second level of the index (which is user) into the columns.

Comment: Thanks for your response, if possible could you please explain it.

Comment: Tell me if you understand

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
pd.concat([df1.set_index(['index', 'user_name']), df2.set_index(['index', 'user_name']), df3.set_index(['index', 'user_name'])], axis=1).unstack().dropna(1)
```